# How to remove all packages I installed via pip and without virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip

I have installed some packages by accident without being in a virtual environment. Thus I wish to uninstall all packages, I installed via pip.

This does not work:

`$ pip freeze -l > dump.txt 
$ cat dump.txt | xargs pip uninstall -y`

Because:

```
Uninstalling python-ldap-3.0.0:
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leonhard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/basecommand.py", line 228, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/leonhard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 68, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "/home/leonhard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 661, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/home/leonhard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 219, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/leonhard/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 273, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 314, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 266, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 264, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Keine Berechtigung: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap/asyncsearch.py'
```

Is there an easy way to uninstall all locally install python packages?

Comment: This is very dangerous, as the operating system sometimes installs python packages that are needed for the OS to work. For example, Debian/Ubuntu/Fedore do that. It's very tricky to clean that.

Comment: I do not want to uninstall packages installed by the operating system. I just want to install those installed by pip.

Comment: I know, but there's no way to see the difference

Comment: So the answer is, that there is no automated way? It is not as dangerous as you said because I do not uninstall with sudo. Thus pip can't destroy a thing.

Answer (score 1):

since I cant post just comments, you can try this command: `pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)`. It clears your user packages folder outside of the context of a virtualenv. Try this command with care.

Comment: It does not work: $ pip uninstall -y -r <(pip freeze)
Cannot uninstall 'ipython-genutils'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: You can read about this error message here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5247 Hope this helps.